# delete duplicate rows in Fortran77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a file which is a table of 119 columns (separated by spaces) and around 50000 rows (lines). I would like to remove the duplicated entries, i.e. those rows which have all identical columns (119). I sketched this code:

```
      PROGRAM deldup

      IMPLICIT NONE

      DOUBLE PRECISION PAR(119),PAR2(119)
      INTEGER I,J,K,LINE,TREP
      CHARACTER filename*40

c Get the input file name
      CALL getarg(1,filename)

c File where the results will be stored.
      OPEN(29, FILE="result.dat", STATUS='UNKNOWN')

c Current line number
      LINE=0
c counting repeated points
      TREP=0

 101  LINE=LINE+1
      OPEN(27, FILE=filename, STATUS='OLD')

c     Verifying that we are not in the first line... and we read the
c     corresponding one
      IF (LINE.NE.1) THEN 
         DO K=1,LINE-1
            READ(27,11,ERR=103,END=9999)
         END DO
      ENDIF
      READ(27,11,ERR=103,END=9999) (PAR(I),I=1,119)

c     Start comparing line by line looking for matches. If a match is
c     found , close the
c     file and open it again to read the next line. If the end of file is
c     reached and not iqual rows found, write the line in "results.dat"

 102  READ(27, 11,END=104, ERR=102) (PAR2(I),I=1,119)
      DO J=1,119
         IF ( PAR(J).NE.PAR2(J) ) THEN
            GOTO 102
         ELSEIF (J.EQ.119) THEN
            TREP=TREP+1
            GOTO 103
         ENDIF
      END DO

 104  WRITE(29,11) (PAR(I),I=1,119)

 103  CLOSE(27)
      GOTO 101

 9999 WRITE(*,*) "DONE!,", TREP, "duplicated points found!"
      CLOSE(27)
      CLOSE(28)
      CLOSE(29)

 11   FORMAT(200E14.6)
      END
```

which actually works it is just super slow. Why? Is there any library that I can use? Sorry for my ignorance, I am completely new with Fortran77.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each line you open and close the original file, which is very slow! To speed things up, you could just use `rewind`.

The main issue, though, is the complexity of your algorithm: `O(n^2)` [You compare each line to every other line]. As a start, I would keep a list of unique line, and compare against that list. If a new row is already listed, discard it - if not, it is a new unique row. This would reduce the complexity to `O(n*m)`, with (hopefully) `m << n` (m is the number of unique rows). Sorting the rows will probably speed up the comparison.

The next remark would be to move from I/O to memory! Read in the complete file into an array, or at least keep the list of unique rows in memory. A 50,000x119 double precision array requires ~45MB of RAM, so I think this should be feasible ;-)
Write the result back in one piece in a final step.

Comment: That is very useful, thank you very much indeed!! :). By the way, to read the whole table into an array is ok if I do this:
      LINES=1
      MAXL=100000

      DO I=1,MAXL
         READ(30,11, END=999) (PAR(I,J),J=1,NPAR)
      END DO   
999 .....

or there's another fastest way?

Comment: 11   FORMAT(119E14.6)

Answer (score 0):

First question: Why stick with Fortran 77?  Since g95 and gfortran have come along, there is no real reason to use a standard that has been obsolete for more than twenty years.

The canonical way to remove duplicate is to sort them, remove duplicates, and then output them in the original order.  If you use a good sorting algorithm such as quicksort or heapsort, this will give you O(n log n) performance.

One additional remark: It is also a good idea to put magic numbers such as 119 in your program into PARAMETER statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips @tkoenig . I use Fortran77 just because my boss wants to.